# Как в Linux Mint задать сочетание кнопок для "свернуть все окна"

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde

Приветствую, у меня версия 18.2 KDE, хочу настроить сочетание клавиш как в винде(win + d), но в упор не могу найти такого хоткея

Comment: `ctrl+alt+d` не пашет?

Comment: @donRumata Да мне вполне хватило той подсказки, просто я привык к винвовому сочетанию, и надоело что раз 10 я автоматически пробовал выскочить на рабочий стол

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетания клавиш
находим Пункт "свернуть все окна" и назначаем сочетание.